# Generate and Read Word Embeddings with KeyedVectors

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I trained a neural network with tensorflow and extracted the weights from the embedding layer to make an array of embeddings. I generated it as a txt file and I can't read it with KeyedVectors
Generate the file.

Generate the file

```
import io
out_vectors = io.open('vecs.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
out_vectors.write(f'{vocab_size} {embedding_dim}')
for word_num in range(1,vocab_size):
  word = reversed_word_index[word_num]
  embeddings = weights[word_num]
  line_embedding ='\n' + word + '\t'+ '\t'.join([str(x) for x in embeddings]) 
  out_vectors.write(line_embedding)
  
out_vectors.close()
```

Read the file

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
model_embedding = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('vecs.txt')
```

Comment: What do you mean "can't read it"? Is there an error you could describe in your question text? If no error, is there some problem with the resulting `KeyedVectors` instance? What's the code/output/etc that's suggested things have failed?

Answer (score -1):

try to add a lambda method (mmap) in loading function, should look like:

```
model_embedding = KeyedVectors.load("vecs.txt", mmap="r")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).